# Advection diffusion equation with position dependent advection

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am trying to solve a equation that looks like $$u_t=f(x)u_x+Du_{xx}$$
any insight to whether an solution might exist would be very much appreciated!

Comment: for an advection-diffusion equation you need $[f(x)u]_x$, not $f(x)u_x$; an overview of existence conditions is given, for example, in https://doi.org/10.1155/2014/450417